# Heroku pipeline (for GitHub review app) keeps disappearing

Tags: heroku, heroku-review-app

We're setting up review apps with GitHub integration.

We followed this:
[https://help.heroku.com/R8AE3YBV/why-did-my-pipeline-disappear#:~:text=If%20you%20do%20not%20have,the%20pipeline%20is%20automatically%20deleted](https://help.heroku.com/R8AE3YBV/why-did-my-pipeline-disappear#:%7E:text=If%20you%20do%20not%20have,the%20pipeline%20is%20automatically%20deleted).

and created a default dummy app for our review app pipeline.

It works fine in the first couple of builds and review apps...

Then the pipeline keeps disappearing from our dashboard :( (seems deleted).

Why and how to fix that?

Comment: You have access to the apps connected to the pipeline?

Comment: Yes, it worked ok but it keeps disappearing